# Simulink - Finding index of vector element where accumulation crosses a threshold

Tags: signal-processing, simulink

I'm looking to improve the delay estimation portion of a Simulink model. The input is an estimated impulse response for the system. I want the index of the first sample of the impulse response where the sum of the absolute values of it and the previous elements exceeeds a certain fraction of the total across the whole vector.

Here's my current solution:
[image: Screenshot of Simulink model]

The matrix sum runs along dimension 2. The prelookup block is set to clip. This is finding the element (possibly one off, I haven't thought that through yet) where 1% of the total is reached.

This seems overly complicated, and it isn't clear what it is trying to do without some explanation. I tried coming up with a solution based on the discrete integrator/accumulator block but couldn't come up with something better. It certainly does a lot more addition than it needs to with this solution, although performance isn't really an issue right now.

Is there a simpler way to get the running sum across a vector that I could put in place of the Toeplitz->Triangular->Sum section? Is there a better way overall to perform the whole lookup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have DSP System toolbox, there is a "Cumulative Sum" block which should be able to replace your toeplitz, traiangular matrix and matrix sum.

http://www.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/cumulativesum.html

If you do not have DSP System toolbox, I suggest coding this in MATLAB Function block where it should be a one liner.

```
y = cumsum(x);
```

While you are there you may also want to code the entire logic in MATLAB Function block which in cases like this is easier to code and understand.

Comment: Thanks - that looks like what I needed. I think when I looked at that block before I missed that it would do it per vector, and thought I would need to set up a trigger to reset the accumulator every time a new one came in.